# Ocultar todos los marcadores al mostrar una ruta

Tags: javascript, google-maps

intento ocultar todos los marcadores de mi mapa al calcular un ruta. Se que con el metodo .setMap(null) se pueden desaparecer los marcadores, pero no se en que parte de mi código puedo escribirlo.
Yo intente ponerlo dentro de la función que dibuja la ruta, pero con eso, solo consigo ocultar el ultimo marcador.

Soy principiante en Javascript, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
var marcas, map;
    function iniciarMap() {
        var optionMap = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.39933049527024, 2.1970036625316425),
            styles: [{
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [
                    { "visibility": "off" }
                ]
            }]
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAqui'), optionMap);
        var extencion = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var serviceDir = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var displayDir = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            suppressMarkers: false,
            preserveViewport: true,
        });
        displayDir.setMap(map);
        var baresP = [];
        baresP.push({ lat: 41.40288966232697, lng: 2.198766893752577, bar: 'Xorus', id: 'ChIJ0UGVLDyjpBIRdNcVCTidgPs', img: 'image/xorus.jpg', descp: 'Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/LaTavernicola/', fono: '603 307 117', address: 'calle granada 90', });
        baresP.push({ lat: 41.3983979113559, lng: 2.204631508368948, bar: 'Blue Bar', id: 'ChIJpa-3z2qjpBIRUW4SwqLY7mk', img: 'image/bluebar.jpg', descp: 'Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/LaTavernicola/', fono: '93 280 90 59', address: ' Pallars, 122', });
        baresP.push({ lat: 41.39684988162788, lng: 2.192088531196873, bar: 'D9', id: 'ChIJnVDdoRmjpBIR8Ra7Fpj8nxE', img: 'image/d9.jpg', descp: 'Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/LaTavernicola/', fono: '93 667 74 54', address: 'Rambla de Poblenou 44-46', });
        baresP.push({ lat: 41.400050872923345, lng: 2.2028905449215017, bar: 'El Tío Ché', id: 'ChIJxxFIXhWjpBIRv6GISCWyg3k', img: 'image/tioche.jpg', descp: 'Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/LaTavernicola/', fono: '93 485 45 63', address: 'Roc boronat 70', });

        var infoVent, i;
        function mostrarmarcas() {
            for ( i = 0; i < baresP.length; i++) {
                marcas = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(baresP[i].lat, baresP[i].lng),
                    map: map,
                    title: "hola",
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
                extencion.extend(baresP[i])
            };
        };
        mostrarmarcas();
        map.fitBounds(extencion);
        var option, e

        function verRutas() {
            var caja = document.getElementById('destino');
            for (e = 0; e < baresP.length; e++) {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = baresP[e].id;
                option.text = baresP[e].bar;
                option.id = "lhoa";
                caja.add(option);

                var onCambiarRuta = function () {
                    mostrarRuta(serviceDir, displayDir);
                };

                document.getElementById('destino').addEventListener('change', onCambiarRuta);

                function mostrarRuta(serviceDir, displayDir) {
                    serviceDir.route({
                        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3976537, 2.1941345, 17),
                        destination: { placeId: document.getElementById('destino').value },
                        travelMode: 'WALKING'
                    }, function (response, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK') {
                            displayDir.setDirections(response);

                                marcas.setMap(null); // con esta linea solo desaparece el ultimo marcador


                        }
                        /*else {
                            window.alert('hay un error en: ' + status)
                        }*/
                    });
                }
            };

        };
        verRutas();


    };
```

Comment: has probado la funcion map.clear()?

Comment: Si, pero sin resultados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es crear una variable tipo `array` que almacene las marcas a medida que las vas creando.

Actualmente solo almacenas una marca a la vez de acuerdo a los datos que tienes en `baresP`. Es por eso que cuando finaliza el ciclo en el cual creas las marcas, solo la última marca está en la variable.

Puedes además crear una función para limpiar las marcas, eso luego te permitiría mayor flexibilidad si vas a extender tu código.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea ocultar todos los marcadores de una ruta establecida con la API de Google Maps.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la tarea usaremos una variable tipo `array` que almacene las marcas mientras se crea la ruta. También usaremos el método `setMap()` y le pasaremos como argumento `null`.

El código puede quedar así:

```
var marcas[]
var map;
function iniciarMap() {
    var optionMap = {...} // tus opciones

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAqui'), optionMap);
    var extencion = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var serviceDir = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var displayDir = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: false,
        preserveViewport: true,
    });
    displayDir.setMap(map);
    var baresP = [];
    baresP.push(...); //llenas tu array
    var infoVent, i;

    // En esta función creas las marcas, aquí llenarás el array
    function mostrarmarcas() {
        for ( i = 0; i < baresP.length; i++) {
            //IMPORTANTE aqui llenas array[i]
            marcas[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(baresP[i].lat, baresP[i].lng),
                map: map,
                title: "hola",
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            extencion.extend(baresP[i])
        };
    };
    mostrarmarcas();
    map.fitBounds(extencion);
    var option, e

    //Esta función limpia las marcas del mapa
    function limpiarMarcas() {
        for(var i=0; i < marcas.length; i++) {
            marcas[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function verRutas() {
        var caja = document.getElementById('destino');
        for (e = 0; e < baresP.length; e++) {
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = baresP[e].id;
            option.text = baresP[e].bar;
            option.id = "lhoa";
            caja.add(option);

            var onCambiarRuta = function () {
                mostrarRuta(serviceDir, displayDir);
            };

            document.getElementById('destino').addEventListener('change', onCambiarRuta);

            function mostrarRuta(serviceDir, displayDir) {
                serviceDir.route({
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3976537, 2.1941345, 17),
                    destination: { placeId: document.getElementById('destino').value },
                    travelMode: 'WALKING'
                }, function (response, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        displayDir.setDirections(response);
                        // aqui llamas a la función que creaste para limpiar las marcas
                        limpiarMarcas();
                    }
                    /*else {
                        window.alert('hay un error en: ' + status)
                    }*/
                });
            }
        };
    };
    verRutas();
};
```

Espero que así soluciones tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciono a la perfección.